# Squares of differentiable functions

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose I have a function $f$ such that $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x$. Suppose that $f^2$ is differentiable. Is it necessarily true that $f$ is differentiable?

I was thinking of 
$$
f(x) = (-1)^x
$$
but this doesn't satisfy the first hypothesis, so I'm wondering about a way to prove that this is true, or a counterexample. Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: $\lvert x\rvert$. Whenever $f$ has a zero, you can't infer the differentiability of $f$ in that point from the differentiability of $f^2$.

Comment: By $f^2$ do you mean $f\circ f$ or $x\mapsto (f(x))^2$?

Comment: Sorry @dfeuer I meant $(f(x))^2$. Thanks Daniel Fischer!